# Sorting rows through tds but issue with using nodelist

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying  to sort a table without theads so I won't be using a jQuery plugin. The problem is that when I try and use .children in a loop I get the error of .children is not a function. This is because of I am using a node list not an array but I couldn't seem to convert it using 
 Array.prototype.slice.call.

```
var rows = $('.sort').find('tr');
console.log(rows);
var i;
var temp;

for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
    if(rows[i].children('td').text()<rows[i+1].children('td').text()){
    temp=rows[i];
    rows[i]=rows[i+1].children('td').text();
    rows[i+1]=temp;
     }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k1tcc7to/

Comment: You should use `$.each` instead of `for`

Comment: @Arrvi: You mean `$.fn.each`? But that won't help much, no.

Comment: Just use `$(rows[i]).children('td')…`

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call` involves JS objects, aren't your objects $jQ? If you were to use `querySelectorAll()` to gather your your NodeList, then use  `Array.prototype.slice.call` should work. Or stick to jQuery and use `toArray()`?

Comment: none of these method will allow me to use .children since it is a prototype of nodelist

Comment: Arrvi how am I supposed to access each different arrow element to sort it then. 
Bergie I tried but won't work with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." with .children.
Zer00 .children is jquery though